# How to use the UISearchControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

When I am coding something about Table View, I found that

UISearchDisplayDelegate(&UISearchDisplayController) was deprecated since IOS8

Official API Document imported the

UISearchControllerDelegate(&UISearchController)

The **old Delegate** can do many tasks(we know API Document categorizes the functions into tasks that those classes can do)such as:

---

[Search State Change]

---

[Loading and Unloading the table view]

---

[Showing and Hiding the table view]

---

[Responding to Changes in Search Criteria]

---

**However**,the **newest Delegate** just contains one kind of task:

[Presenting and Dismissing the SearchController]
-->(contains 4 functions, 2 for each presenting and dismissing )

What makes me confused is HOW can I use such a tiny number of functions to fulfill the requirements such as : change the searching conditions of String -or- Hiding the Search Bar(set the height of Search Bar)when it is not needed.

**For instance**,in this todo apps,I have 2 arrays: todos(contains all the data) & filteredtodos(contains the data with **keywords**)

Then I add a [Search Bar and Search Display] component upon the TableView

and next I go to find the prototype of functions in the [UISearchDisplayDelegate] called:

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool
{
        filteredTodos = todos.filter(){
                 $0.title.rangeOfString(searchString) != nil
        }
        return true
}
```

to filter the keywords.

And display the cells in normal condition or searching condition

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        if(tableView == searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView){//Deprecated!!!
            return filteredTodos.count//Searching Display
        }else{
            return todos.count//Normal Display
        }
    }
```

The Xcode hints told me that the usage of **searchDisplayController** was deprecate.

HOPE you will help me out!!! Appreciate!!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Unfortunately,there is no homework,and I am just doing those self-learning jobs:)Thank you

Comment: I don't mean that this is homework, what I mean is to show your work. Show what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: OK,I was misunderstood. The low reputation can't up load any images.But I will try to narrate them.

Comment: Please don't upload a bunch of images unless absolutely necessary. Just post the relevant text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's docs:

```
protocol UISearchResultsUpdating : NSObjectProtocol {

// Called when the search bar's text or scope has changed or when the search bar becomes first responder.
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
}
```

Have your view controller conform to `UISearchResultsUpdating` and it should solve your problem.